# EF Power Tools Beta 2: System.MissingMethodException thrown by 'Reverse Engineer Code First'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have the 'Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2' installed and I want to simply reverse map my database schema. I right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and click 'Entity Framework->Reverse Engineer Code First', specify the connection properties and I get the following error in the output window. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Xml.XmlReader System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetConceptualSchemaDescription()'.
    at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.GetProviderSchemaMetadataWorkspace(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection providerConnection)
    at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString)
    at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, String namespaceName)
    at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)
```

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you using?

Comment: .NET version - 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Entity Framework June 2011 CTP is installed on your box. You need uninstall it. See more details here: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/04/11/entity-framework-zombie-a-k-a-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp/